# Why is the opacity of my ellipse changing automatically when I don't actually change it in the code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app

I have an Ellipse in my Windows Universal App and I want to change its fill color when the mouse enters and leaves that ellipse. All I want to do is change the color and nothing else. However the opacity automatically decreases whenever I enter my mouse. Can you please find out the problem in my code.

Thank you.

XAML

```
        <Ellipse x:Name="glamourEllipse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="594,260,0,0" Stroke="#FFB43F3F" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Tapped="glamour_Tapped">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFB43C3C"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90.254"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
```

C#

```
    SolidColorBrush hoverBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

    private void mouse_Enter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 140, 40, 40);
        hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
        nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;

    }

    private void mouse_Exit(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 180, 60, 60);
        hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
        nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an animation set up somewhere, like in a style?

Comment: Try `Color.FromArgb(255, 140, 40, 40)` and `Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 60, 60)`

Comment: @RonBeyer it worked without animation. Do i really need to set up an animation/

Comment: @user3716672 No, he just wanted to make sure you didn't accidentally set an animation anywhere.

Comment: Yes, what @EBrown said, other animations can override what you do in code so I wanted to make sure you weren't fighting an animation.

Comment: Everybody gets a chance to work with various numeral systems nowadays.

Comment: @RonBeyer No, it happened to be a simple case of expecting `100` to mean `100%`, when it actually means `64`. Sometimes the simplest of issues are often overlooked - even by the experts.

Comment: @Dusan Indeed, though the OP could also use HEX there to eliminate mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you **are** changing the transparency in the `MouseEnter` and `MouseExit` events:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FFB43C3C"/>
```

This line sets the colour to `255 alpha, 180 red, 60 green and 60 blue`. Your code on the other hand:

```
hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 140, 40, 40);
hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 180, 60, 60);
```

Both lines specify an `alpha` of `100`. Now, in our `decimal` system of mathematics this would be perfectly valid and mean `100%` opacity, but in the `8-bit` and `32-bit` world of the computer, it's not. Basically, that code sets the alpha to `64` hex. (Change the `FF` in the XAML and you will see the transparency is the same.)

That overload of `Color.FromArgb` expects that `0` is transparent, and `255` is opaque.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Basically, change `100` to `255` in both of those `Color.FromArgb` lines and you're golden.

```
private void mouse_Enter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 140, 40, 40);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}

private void mouse_Exit(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 60, 60);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}
```

Or, remove that value altogether.

```
private void mouse_Enter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(140, 40, 40);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}

private void mouse_Exit(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(180, 60, 60);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}
```

Both options have the same effect overall. The second one also guarantees you don't accidentally do it again, as the `alpha` will **always** be `255` with it.

Edit: Lastly, for completeness, you could use Hexadecimal in the code as well, which may be the better option as it's all the same that way:

```
private void mouse_Enter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x8C, 0x28, 0x28);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}

private void mouse_Exit(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xB4, 0x3C, 0x3C);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}
```

Or:

```
private void mouse_Enter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0x8C, 0x28, 0x28);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}

private void mouse_Exit(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hoverBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0xB4, 0x3C, 0x3C);
    hoverBrush.Opacity = 1;
    nsfwEllipse.Fill = hoverBrush;
}
```